# Mapbox gl js draw multiple layers after map is loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, mapbox-gl-js

I have to display many (~1 million) GPS coordinates using Mapbox gl js. I have multiple sequential Ajax requests that take care of fetching the data from a server. What I would like to do is to add a layer to the map after each Ajax request and have it displayed immediately.

The problem is that if I put the code inside the `map.on('style.load', function() {})` event, the map is not displayed until the last Ajax call has terminated. What I currently have is something like this:

```
function loadData(finished) {
    if (finished) {
        return;
    }
    // do ajax request and wait for completion
    // if last request, set finished = true
    // call to map.addSource()
    // call to map.addLayer()
    // recursive call to loadData()
}

map.on("style.load", function() {
    loadData();
});
```

Do you know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by substituting the map.on(...) call with the following:

```
function waitForMapLoaded() {
    if(!map.loaded()) {
        window.setTimeout(waitForMapLoaded, 100);
    } else {
        loadData();
    }
}
waitForMapLoaded();
```